# I need help with quotations and punctuation

Tags: punctuation, quotations

How do I punctuate when using quotes?

> “There were more?” Asked Wendy.

or;

> "There were more," asked Wendy?

---

> "He was amazing!" Exclaimed Billy.

or;

> "He was amazing," exclaimed Billy!

Answer (score 10):

Although the first version in each case is closer to being appropriate, neither is completely correct.

The sentences should be formatted as follows:

> "There were more?" asked Wendy.
>   "He was amazing!" exclaimed Billy.

Although question and exclamation marks normally end a sentence, if they come before a quotation mark in the middle of mixed dialogue where the sentence continues, then the sentence does not *actually* end and there shouldn't be a capital letter indicating it does.

Therefore, the next word has its initial letter in lowercase. (Unless, of course, it's a proper name or some other word that would have a capital letter regardless of its position in any sentence.)

---

You may find Beth Hill's blog post ["Punctuation in Dialogue"](http://theeditorsblog.net/2010/12/08/punctuation-in-dialogue/) to be useful. It addresses this and similar issues.

Comment: Yep. And if the sentence continues after the end of the quote, then a comma will usually only replace a period (or a lack of punctuation) at the end of the quote; question marks and exclamation points in the quote will remain and not be replaced with a comma.